# What do you call a person who does not take risks (or who does not like taking risks)?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want one word which best suits a person who does not take risks (or one who does not like taking risks).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I suggest *cautious; circumspect; risk-averse.* Those may not quite fit, but you can probably look up synonyms which may be better.

Answer (score 14):

There's the relatively new term, found in psychology, business, economics, politics, etc. *risk averse*.

If you want to cast the tendency in a very negative light, there is *coward* and a great many colloquial and slang terms along that line, some of which are offensive (*chicken, yellow, pussy, pusillanimous, chicken-shit*).

More neutral, and less jargon-ish than *risk averse*, would be *cautious, wary, timid*.

More positive would be *judicious, prudent*.

Comment: **prudent** would get my vote.

Comment: Changed "adverse" to "averse".

Comment: +1 for writing _pusillanimous_ and _chicken shit_ in the same sentence.

Comment: Thanks @RussellMcMahon though you missed where I repeated the mistake (make a mistake once and it's easy to keep doing it), fixed now.

Comment: @terdon if you ever want to vocally call someone a coward, I strongly recommend using *pusillanimous* and *chicken-shit* in the same noun phrase; there's a quality to the gestalt of "You pusillanimous chicken-shit!" that neither word has on its own.

Comment: I think *chicken-shit* alludes to the comparative worthlessness of the substance, rather than the proverbial cowardice of the shitter.

Answer (score 3):

> **pru·dent**   /ˈpro͞odnt/ Adjective Acting with or showing care and
>   thought for the future. Synonyms cautious - discreet - wary - careful
>   - circumspect
>
> **cau·tious**   /ˈkôSHəs/ Adjective Attentive to potential problems or
>   dangers. (of an action) Characterized by such an attitude. Synonyms
>   wary - careful - prudent - circumspect - chary - discreet

and my personal favourite

> **cir·cum·spect**   /ˈsərkəmˌspekt/ Adjective Wary and unwilling to take
>   risks. Synonyms cautious - wary - prudent - careful - discreet

Comment: +1. I like "cautious". But I haven't heard "circumspect" being used to mean specifically avoiding risks. I thought it was more to do with making well-considered decisions. What dictionary did you use?

Comment: I used the broadest dictionary I know: I googled "circumspect definition", which gave me Web definitions from Dictionary.com, Answers.com, Merriam-Webster, The Free Dictionary, and others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to someone who does not take risks because they are very careful in making decisions or in dealing with anything, you could consider *'[meticulous](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/meticulous)'*, too.

Comment: Sky divers tend to be extremely meticulous when it comes to their parachutes, but aren't normally considered disinclined to take risks. Certainly one reason to be meticulous is to reduce certain risks (those caused by carelessness), but it does nothing to reduce other risks, and is not the sole reason for being meticulous (pride in a craft would be a strong reason, not much related to risk, as would sheer enjoyment of a task which would have no connection to risk at all).

Comment: @JonHanna: Point taken. But if one wishes not to take risks, one has to be meticulous. And the one who is meticulous, often avoids risks. So I believe, _'meticulous'_ does have something to do with not taking risks.

Answer (score 1):

You could call such a person a [pussyfooter](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pussyfoot) who would be someone who acts "in a cautious or non-committal way". He/she would also be considered *conservative* or simply *defensive*.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer I thought of (and before reading Andrew Leach's comment) is **risk-adverse**, which would seem to fit your definition exactly.

Comment: * risk-**averse**

Answer (score 0):

**Scaredy cat** n. *Informal*
One who is excessively fearful.

When I was a girl attending a London school way back in the mid-70s, the kids used to play a game called "Dare" or a similar name, basically you dared your *mate* to do something really *hard* and/or *shameful*. For example, boys were often challenged to go into the girls' toilets, in those day the buildings were adjacent to the school playground, so everyone could see. If they refused, everyone would chant:  **"scaredy cat**, **scaredy cat**". I don't remember the tune any more but I remember the scorching humiliation whenever I refused a "dare"...